# linq to xml - display results based on array or list

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file on which I want to make a query to display all articles with certain Id's in it.This is what I tried but somehow I can't get it to work.
I looked around and all I could find were examples using linq to sql.

Any help would be appreciated...

Cheers,
Terry

The id's are stored like this in the xml

```
<relatedcontent articleID="1, 2, 3, 4" />
```

Here's my linq

```
 var mylinks = (from item in relatedLinks.Descendants("link") 
    where item.Attribute("linkID").Value.Contains("1, 2")
        select new
          {
            testlink = item.Value
          });

    foreach (var newarticles in mylinks)
       {
         Response.Write(newarticles .testlink);
       }
```

Comment: The Tower of London should be reopened temporarily for the purpose of torturing the person who put that comma-separated attribute there.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the XML?  Also, what is 'relatedLinks'?  It's too hard to give an answer without seeing more, but it's possible that your item.Attribute("linkID") should be item.Attribute("articleID") instead.

Comment: Dave, you are so right! Two Words "legacy code"... Will try to change the format into seperate items..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing now is to look for articles where the Id contains the string "1, 2", like if the Id was "5, 8, 1, 2, 9".

What you want is probably the opposite; to find the articles where "1, 2" contains the Id, i.e. the articles with Id "1" and "2":

```
var ids = new HashSet<string>();
ids.Add("1");
ids.Add("2");

var mylinks =
  from item in relatedLinks.Descendants("link") 
  where ids.Contains(item.Attribute("linkID").Value)
  select new { testlink = item.Value };
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, that is exactly what I try to achieve. Somehow though, it only gets the first item. I tried adding the ids to a <list>, same effect. Any suggetions?

Comment: Found the solution. In the xml the numbers have a space also, hen splitting the string I didn't get rid of them. Thanks for help...